# Route Protection in React. Backend not able to process JWT Tokens

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, jwt

I have made this project specifically to practice Authentication and Security. But for god's sake I cannot get this thing to work. I am using a Node.js mongoDB backend and react frontend. And so far I have managed to send a Jwt token from the server and store it in the Browser's local storage. But now I'm stuck on sending this token to the backend for verification and navigate the user to the '/' page if he/she tries to access the '/messages' route before logging in. Here is the code. I'm using axios to handle http requests and react-router-dom to handle routes.

App.jsx

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from './pages/Login'
import Register from './pages/Register'
import Messages from './pages/Messages'

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/messages' element={<Messages />}/>
      <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
      <Route index element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}

export default App
```

Messages.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Messages = () => {

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const [emptyErrorMessage, setemptyErrorMessage] = useState(false);

    const postMessage = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!message) setemptyErrorMessage(true);
        else {
            await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/messages', {message});
            window.location.reload(false);
        }

    } 
    
    const getMessages = async () => {

        try {
            const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/messages', {
                headers : {
                    'Authorization': token
                }
            });
            setMessages(res.data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            if (err.response.status == 401) {
                navigate('/');
            }
        }

    }

    useEffect(() => {
       getMessages();
    }, []);

  return (
    <div>
        <form>
            <label>Message:</label><br />
            <input type="text" onChange={e => setMessage(e.target.value)} name='message' autoComplete='off'/>
            {emptyErrorMessage ? <h5>This Field is required</h5> : null}

            <button type='submit' onClick={postMessage}>Submit</button>
        </form>

        {messages && messages.length > 0 ? messages.map(singleMessage => {
            return <h4 key={singleMessage._id}>{singleMessage.message}</h4>
        }) : <h1>No messages Yet</h1>}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Messages
```

Login.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const Login = () => {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const postLoginData = async () => {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/auth/login', {
            email,
            password
        });

        if (res.data.status == 200) {
            const token = res.data.token;
            localStorage.setItem('token', token);
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `${token}`;
            navigate('/messages')
        } else window.location.reload(false);
    }   

  return (
    <>
        <div className="login-form">

            <form>

                <label>Email:</label>
                <input type="email" onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} name='email' />

                <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} name='password' />
                
            </form>

            <button onClick={postLoginData}>Login</button>

            <br />
            <a href="/register">Or register</a>

        </div>
    </>
    )
}

export default Login
```

That's it for the frontend. Here are the Backend Controllers.

userRoutes.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import { loginUser, registerUser } from '../controllers/userController.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/login', loginUser)
router.post('/register', registerUser)

export default router;
```

messageRoutes.js:

```
import express  from "express";
import { postMessage, getMessage } from "../controllers/messageControllers.js";
import verifyToken from '../middleware/verifyToken.js';


const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', postMessage);
router.get('/', verifyToken, getMessage);

export default router;
```

verifyToken.js:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers.Authorization;

    if (!authHeader) return res.status(401).json({ status: 401 });

    try {
        const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, `${process.env.JWT_SECRET}`)
    
        console.log(decoded);
        next()
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

}

export default verifyToken;
```

messagesController.js

```
import Message from '../models/messageSchema.js'

export const postMessage = async (req, res) => {
    const {message} = req.body;

    const newMessage = new Message ({
        message: message
    });

    await newMessage.save();
    res
    .status(200)
    .json({ status: 200 });
}

export const getMessage = async (req, res) => {
    const messages = await Message.find({}).exec();
    res.send(messages);
}
```

userController.js

```
import User from "../models/userSchema.js";
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import generateToken from '../middleware/generateToken.js'

export const loginUser = async (req, res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body;

    try {
        if (!email || !password) throw Error('All fields must be filled')

        const potentialUser = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (!potentialUser) throw Error("Invalid Login Credentials");

        const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, potentialUser.password)
        if (!match) throw Error("Invalid Login Credentials");

        const token = generateToken(potentialUser._id);

        res
        .status(200)
        .json({
            email,
            token,
            status: 200
        })
    } catch (err) {
        res
        .status(400)
        .json({ err: err.message })
    }
}

export const registerUser = async (req, res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body;

    try {
        if (!email || !password) throw Error('All fields must be filled')

        const userExists = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (userExists) {
            throw Error('User Already Exists');
        }

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        const user = new User ({
            email,
            password: hashedPassword
        })

        const token = generateToken(user._id);
        await user.save();

        res
        .status(200)
        .json({ status: 200, token });

    } catch(err) {
        res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: err.message })
    }

}
```

A little Context on routes:
I the endpoint for the routes is defined in the main server file which I have not provide since I believe the Error does not come from there. To access /login or /register. The complete path is /auth/login and same for register. In the frontend, the '/' is the login route and '/register' is the register route. Both of the Routes are public. The '/messages' route should be protected. Which it is not.

Expected Behavior:
If the User logs in with the correct Username and password, a token is generated and stored in the Browser's local storage, and the User is navigated to '/messages'. But if Someone tries to access '/messages' without logging in, the user should be redirected to the login page.

Actual Behaviour:
With the code I provided, regardless of wheather the username and password match or not, I'm redirected to the login page. Which is obvious because at this point I have messed a lot with this code. Also when I'm sending the token as an Authorization header and try to console log it in the backend, it turns out that there is no such authorization header.

Note:
The code provided might not make complete sense. Please take into consideration that there might be a lot of irregularities in the way data is being handled in the Messages.jsx and VerifyToken functions. Also It would be great how to handle requests using authorization headers in axios and how to verify tokens.

I believe the problem might exist in the Messages.jsx file and the Verify Token function. Although it also might be one of the userControllers.

Comment: For security you may write your route like this `{token ?   <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} /> :  <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>} /> }` It will automatically redirect the user to Login in case of accessing messages before login.

Comment: I'm Already signing the token with 'Bearer' as prefix, since it wasn't there as default. And your solution does not seem to be working also it's not a complete solution to the problem. @pavel savva

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have enough rating to post a comment, but right off the bat it looks like your `verifyToken` function expects the Authorization header to have two words separate by a space with the second word being the actual token: `const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];`, but it looks like your are only sending the token by itself in your `axios` requests. By convention, you would usually have `Authorization: Bearer xxx` where `xxx` is your token. I think adding a `Bearer`  before your token in the `axios` requests should fix this issue.

I don’t see any other obvious issues with your code. You might want to try watching the `Network` tab in your browser’s DevTools to make sure that the proper `Authorization` header is sent to the server. On the server, you can try adding some `console.log` statements to see if the token comes through to the `verifyToken` function and if it succeeds and if it fails, what error it fails with.